# Operator theory : Matrix Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Definition of Norm : 
Suppose $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix. Then $\|A\|$ is defined by :
\begin{align}
\|A\|= &\sup\{\|Ax\| : \|x\|=1\}\\
     = &\sup\{\|Ax\| : \|x\|\leq 1\}
\end{align}
These two definitions are equivalent. But why?
Please anyone explain..

Comment: since the norm of a vector is homogenous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator norm. Alternative definition](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92556/operator-norm-alternative-definition) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171259/equivalent-definitions-of-the-operator-norm).

Answer (score 3):

Let $\alpha = \sup\{\|Ax\| : \|x\| = 1\}$ and $\beta = \sup\{\|Ax\| : \|x\| \leq 1\}$. Clearly, $\alpha \leq \beta$.

Now, for any $0\neq x \in X$ such that $\|x\| \leq 1$, consider $y = x/\|x\|$. Then $\|y\| = 1$. Then
$$
\|Ay\| \leq \alpha
$$
But
$$
\|Ay\| = \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} \geq \|Ax\|
$$ 
Hence, $\|Ax\| \leq \alpha$, which implies that $\beta \leq \alpha$